# php consulta: siempre tengo que agregar etiquetas html?

Tags: php, html, laravel, mvc

Hoy empece a aprender PHP. Tengo 2 archivos, index.php y test.php.
Mi consulta es: Cada vez que hago un archivo nuevo en PHP, tengo que agregarle las etiquetas "html" "head" y "body" ?

Mirar el ejemplo de abajo:

**index.php**

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Documentos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="POST"
        style="width: 50%; display: block; margin: 5vh auto; border: 5px solid black; background: gold; padding: 2rem; border-radius: 20px;"
        name="datos_usuario" id="datos_usuario">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 2rem; text-align: center; width: 100%;">Tu
                Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_usuario" name="nombre_usuario"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Tu nombre" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="edad" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 2rem; text-align: center; width: 100%;">Edad</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edad_usuario" name="edad_usuario" placeholder="edad"
                autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary"
            style="width: 50%; display: block; margin: auto; background: red; border: none;">Submit</button>
    </form>




    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $usuario = $_POST['nombre_usuario'];
    $edad = $_POST['edad_usuario'];

    if($usuario && $edad >= 18){
        echo ("<h1 class='validado'>Bienvenido $usuario de $edad años.</h1>");
    }else if(!$usuario){
        echo ("<h1 class='no-validado'>Completa con tu nombre, Por favor.</h1>");
    }else if(!$edad){
        echo ("<h1 class='no-validado'>Completa con tu edad, Por favor.</h1>");
    }else if($edad < 18){
        echo ("<h1 class='no-validado'>Eres menor de edad.</h1>");
    }
} 

?>

<a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary" name="volver" id="volver">Desconectarse</a>
```

En resumen: **Al archivo test.php**, ¿Tengo que agregarle las etiquetas de HTML, Body y head? o no es necesario?

La "aplicación" funciona, pero no sé si para la comunidad PHP sería válido no incluir esas etiquetas

Comment: Partamos de identificar, ¿qué función o deber suple el archivo `test.php` dentro de tu desarrollo de PHP?

Comment: @BetaM Seria como una especie de "login", si se completa el campo "nombre" y edad es mayor 18, te lleva a otra pagina

Comment: A lo que voy es que ese archivo por si solo, sólo contiene la lógica para hacer una validación, que seguramente irá incrustado en otro archivo entonces no tiene caso inlcuirle etiquetas HTML

Comment: Una página HTML debe tener las etiquetas `<html>`, `<head>` y `<body>`, pero no es necesario que las pongas en todos los scripts, puedes crear archivos que contengan cada sección e incluirlos (_include_ o _require_) o, mejor aún, usar un sistema de plantillas.

Comment: Gracias a los 2 !

Comment: Si pones de etiqueta laravel, tengo entendido que usas laravel, entonces laravel tiene un sistema de plantillas que te ayuda a ahorrarte bastante tiempo